# ASP.NET Join duplicate results into one and sum other fields

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, join

Currently I have the following table in database dbo.test :

```
agentid | serv | func | com | 
--------+------+------+-----|
ampg    |   1  |   0  |  1  |
jrep    |   0  |   0  |  1  |
ampg    |   1  |   1  |  0  |
jrep    |   1  |   0  |  1  |
```

Desired result:

```
agentid | serv | func | com | 
--------+------+------+-----|
ampg    |   2  |  1   |  1  |
jrep    |   1  |  0   |  2  |
```

So it recognizes same agent id and combines into one row summing up the values of each other column. I will then present it in gridview in visual. Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

SQL Group By:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

```
select 
    agentid,
    sum(serv) [sum_serv],
    sum(func) [sum_func],
    sum(com) [sum_com]
from [table]
group by agentid
```

Comment: You can also put alias for column names for better understanding

Comment: Sorry for the late response but yes i ended up figuring that out during some tests and all works like a charm. Thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select agentid ,sum(serv) as [serv], sum(func) as [func], sum(com) as [com] 
from tablename
group by agentid
```